# Browserify failing with cannot find module "lodash" error for some files

Tags: gruntjs, browserify, grunt-browserify

I am running browserify for an app.js located at some path and it fails everytime with cannot find module `lodash` from `[PATH]`.

```
Running "browserify:build" (browserify) task
Error: Cannot find module 'lodash' from '/var/lib/jenkins/buildcode/output/mydir/app_store_richUI/cartridge/js'
Warning: Error running grunt-browserify. Use --force to continue.
```

The `[PATH]` is same where the app.js file is present. But, if I change the file name to some other js file at same path, it works. So, the scene is that it succeeds for some js file and fails for others at same path.

Can someone suggest something ?

I have the `Browserify.js` script installed globally.

### Browserify.js

```
module.exports = {
        build: {
            files: {
                '<%= settings["local.build.dir"] %>/output/<%= grunt.config("build") %>/app_eyeconic_richUI/cartridge/static/default/js/eyeconic.app.js':'<%= settings["local.build.dir"] %>/output/<%= grunt.config("build") %>/app_eyeconic_richUI/cartridge/js/app.js'
            },
        }
    
}
```

The path is shown correctly in the logs with other files. It fails only with `app.js` file

Comment: What does your `app.js` look like? How do you run browserify?

Comment: Here is my app.js [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6aCHPw9hVVCYmt2c1liQnBUYm8/view?usp=sharing) . I am just running grunt browserify with the browserify config file given above. Strange thing is if i provide any other file instead of app.js at the same path, it works. Which means that path is not a problem here

Comment: Then where does it get `lodash` from? What does that `require` statement look like? Are you sure you have `lodash` installed?

Comment: lodash is installed. i have it in node_modules folder. And i am not sure where to check the require statement. Very new to grunt as such. The thing is i could not find in the task browserify or the app.js that where it is requiring lodash. Plus the very same files work if i provide any other file

Comment: Anyone knows about this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a very trivial issue but took quite some time to resolve.
The issue was that the build suite was at a different location than the build source.
The browserify task contained require statements and it searches for modules in the parent directories so it was not able to find the required module.

After copying the build suite at the same path as the source, it worked.

So currently, my gruntfile.js(and other files/folders in the suite), exports and output directory at are same path.